# On the algberaicity of the universal elliptic curve associated to a torsion free subgroup

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, deformation-theory

So let $\Gamma\subseteq SL_2(\mathbf{Z})$ be a finite index subgroup (not necessarily a congruence subgroup). Recall that we have an action of $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$ on 
$\mathbb{H}=\{z\in\mathbf{C}:\Im(z)>0\}$ by moebius transformations and therefore of $\Gamma$. If $\tau\in\mathbb{H}$ and $[a,b,c,d]=\gamma\in SL_2(\mathbf{Z})$ then we have an isomorphism
of complex tori
$$
\mathbf{C}/(\mathbf{Z}+\tau\mathbf{Z})\rightarrow \mathbf{C}/((a\tau+b)\mathbf{Z}+(c\tau+d))
\mathbf{Z}\rightarrow (\mathbf{C}/\mathbf{Z}+\gamma\tau\mathbf{Z}) \;\;\;\; (*)
$$
where the first map is the identity and the second map is the multiplication by $(c\tau+d)^{-1}$. Let
$$
\tilde{\mathcal{E}}_{\Gamma}=\{(\tau,x):\tau\in\mathbb{H},x\in \mathbf{C}/(\mathbf{Z}+\tau\mathbf{Z})\}
$$
We have a natural left action of $\Gamma$ on $\tilde{\mathcal{E}}_{\Gamma}$ given by
$$
\gamma(\tau,x)=(\gamma\tau,j(\gamma,\tau)^{-1}x),
$$
which is just a reinterpretation of $(*)$. Here $j(\gamma,\tau)=c\tau+d$. We thus get the following family of curves (note that the fibers are not necessarily elliptic curves because of the presence of torsion in $\Gamma$ as K. Buzzard pointed out):
$$
\pi_\Gamma:\Gamma\backslash\tilde{\mathcal{E}}_{\Gamma}=:\mathcal{E}_{\Gamma}\rightarrow Y_{\Gamma}:=\Gamma\backslash \mathbb{H}
$$
In the case where $\Gamma$ is torsion free, we readily see that the fibers are elliptic curves and the the $\Gamma$ action is compatible with the addition on the $tori$ (this somehow justifies the terminology "universal elliptic curve" over $Y_{\Gamma}$).

In general one always has that $Y_{\Gamma}$ is a quasi-projective curve defined over $\mathbf{C}$ (in fact it is always possible to define this curve over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbf{Q}$).

[For example, when $\Gamma=\Gamma_0(N)$ one may look at the modular polynomial $f_N(x,y)\in\mathbf{Z}[x,y]$. Then using the modular interpretation one can show that there exists a (complex analytic) immersion of $Y_{\Gamma_0(N)}$ onto the plane curve $C_N: f_N(x,y)=0$. If I remember correctly, in the finite chart $\mathbf{C}^2$ (for $N$ large enough) the singularities of $C_N$ are nodes and thus one can blow-up these points (over $\mathbf{Q}$!). From this one can construct a complex analytic isomorphism between $Y_{\Gamma_0(N)}$ and the blow-up (which is quasi-projective curve defined over $\mathbf{Q}$.]

So here are 2 natural questions.

**Q1**: Is $\mathcal{E}_{\Gamma}$ quasi-projective (at least when $\Gamma$ is torsion free)?

**Q2**: If the answer is yes, then what is the **cleanest** (and if possible most transparent) way of showing that $\mathcal{E}_{\Gamma}$ is quasi-projective?

So for the second question, the thing that I have in mind would be to 1) construct some complex analytic immersion $\pi:\mathcal{E}_{\Gamma}\rightarrow Z$, where $Z$ is
a quasi-projective surface and 2) performing a sequence of blow-ups on $Z$ I would try to construct an embedding.

**added**: Note that one can always find a normal finite index subgroup $\Gamma'\leq \Gamma$.
Since $\mathcal{E}_{\Gamma}=(\mathcal{E}_{\Gamma'})^{\Gamma/\Gamma'}$ we readily see that if $\mathcal{E}_{\Gamma'}$ is affine then automatically $\mathcal{E}_{\Gamma}$ is affine being the quotient of affine variety by a finite group.

Comment: You have to be careful here. I am not sure that you have written down a family of elliptic curves in general. For example if $-1\in\Gamma$ then you seem to be identifying $(\tau,x)$ with $(\tau,-x)$. There may be similar problems with elliptic points even if $-1\not\in\Gamma$ (for example if $\Gamma=\Gamma_1(3)$). The problem is that your moduli problem is not representable in general, and the way you've set it up I think that in the curve above $\tau$ is the torus you think it is, modulo e.g. its automorphism group, which from what you write is I think not what you want to happen.

Comment: I should of course say that my comments do not pertain to the question (which restricts to the torsion-free case); they just pertain to the background stuff.

Comment: You are right I was a bit careless in the set up

Comment: So I replaced family of elliptic curves for family of curves!

Comment: In general, if $X$ is an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $E\to X$ is an analytic family of elliptic curves, then $E$ is automatically algebraic, and in fact projective over $X$. In particular, if $X$ is quasi-projective, then so is $E$. The point is that the Weierstrass embedding of an elliptic curve into $\mathbb{P}^2$ works in families as well. 

Comment: I see, so I'll try to sketch the argument following your comment

Comment: @Keerthi, I don't quite see how to do it. For example if you take the usual Weierstrass model then you need to exclude the $j$-invariants $1728$ and $0$. If we had a universal elliptic curve over $H/SL_2(\mathbf{Z})$ then we could just take the pullback of the projection $\pi:H/\Gamma\rightarrow H/SL_2(\mathbf{Z})$ but we don't have this..

Comment: Keerthi, on the contrary, the Hopf surface is the easiest example of a non-algebraic surface. It is an analytic surface $(\mathbb C^2-0) / q^{\mathbb Z}$ with evident map to $P^1=(\mathbb C^2-0)/\mathbb C^*$ exhibiting it as a bundle with fiber all elliptic curves isomorphic to $\mathbb C^\* / q^{\mathbb Z}$, but its function field is one dimensional. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_surface

Comment: Good example Ben. One possibility to show algebraicity (which I find a bit complicated) would be to construct a very ample line bundle 
of theta Poincare series and to show that it lift to a suitable compactification of $Y_{\Gamma}$. But such a program looks more complicated that the original question... 

Comment: Hi Ben-By 'family of elliptic curves' I meant a relative elliptic curve in the arithmetic geometer's sense. In particular, it admits a global identity section that Donu calls $\sigma$ below. After that the argument is basically what he sketches, except that I had in mind a semi-continuity and base-change argument to show that $f_*\mathcal{O}(3\sigma)$ is trivial. I'm not sure if these results are true in the analytic category, but my sense was that this is where they in fact originate.

Comment: Okay, I now see the problem with my argument. Even if this sheaf is analytically a line bundle, it need not be one algebraically. 

Comment: I guess for this kind of argument to work, you really need to compactify everything, which is a pain. This is done in Brian Conrad's very meticulous, but still (and probably forever) unpublished notes. See www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~edix/public_html_rennes/brian.ps. The result is Corollary 3.3.5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative take on Donu's argument: Removing the image $\sigma$ of a section of 
$E_\Gamma$ allows one to regard a fiber of $E_{\Gamma}$ as a once-punctured torus $S$. 
(In order to construct a section, use the standard upper half-space model of the Teichmuller space of the tori, so that each marked torus is identified with the fundamental parallelogram $P$ with vertices $0, 1, \omega, \omega+1\in {\mathbb C}$. Then the section is given by the map $\omega\to 0\in P$.) Then $M=E_{\Gamma}\setminus \sigma$ is isomorphic to the quotient of the Teichmuller space $T(S)$ of $S$ by a finite-index torsion-free subgroup $Mod^o_S$ of the mapping class  group $Mod_S$ of $S$. Now, this is a general fact (Deligne-Mumford, et al) that $T(S)/Mod^o_S$ is quasi-projective (for any Riemann surface of finite type). It is not hard to see that DM compactification of $T(S)/Mod^o_S$ is our case will add (among other things) the curve $\sigma$ back to $M$, thus, providing a projective compactification of $M$.

In the special case you are interested in, it seems that quasi-projectivity of $E_{\Gamma}$ was first proven by Kodaira (On compact analytic surfaces. II, III), at least, Shioda (On elliptic modular surfaces, 1972) attributes the result to him.

Addendum: As an alternative to this argument, one can use Ron Livne's thesis "On certain covers of the universal elliptic curve". Livne proves that for every level $N\ge 5$ congruence subgroup $\Gamma(N)$ in the modular group $SL(2, {\mathbb Z})$, the universal elliptic curve over $E(N):={\mathbb H}^2/\Gamma(N)$ admits a degree $d\ge 2$ cyclic branched cover $E_d(N)$, so that the latter  admits a compactification $X_d(N)$ (compatible with branched cover), so that $X_d(N)$ is a general type projective surface. Thus, every $E_\Gamma$ admits a finite regular cover which is biholomorphic to a finite cover over one of the $E_d(N)$'s. Thus, $E_\Gamma$ is quasi-projective.

Livne also refers to Mumford's paper "Prym varieties. I." Contributions to analysis (a collection of papers dedicated to Lipman Bers), pp. 325–350. Academic Press, New York, 1974, for a direct proof of quasi-projectivity of $E(N)$'s. I do not have access to Mumford's  paper, so I cannot say for sure.

Comment: @Misha, do you have a nice reference (which covers the case that I'm interested in) which shows in details why is $T(S)/Mod_S^{\circ}$ algebraic. I would like to see how one uses torsion-freeness in order to deduce algebraicity, which is the whole point in my question.

Comment: One can use S.Wolpert "On obtaining a positive line bundle from the Weil-Petersson class," Amer. J. Math. 107 (1985), no. 6, 1485–1507 (1986). In this paper Wolpert proves that the DM compactification of the moduli space is projective by a local computation, proving positivity of current defined by Weil-Peterson metric, and, hence, positivity of the corresponding line bundle. Since the computation is local, it goes through for finite-index subgroups of the mapping class group. I am also adding an alternative reference for the main result in my main answer.  

Comment: @Hugo: As an alternative to differential-geometric arguments you can use the following: The DM compactification $\bar{M}_{g,n}$ of the moduli space $M_{g,n}=T_{g,n}/Mod_{g,n}$ is projective. Hence, it admits a positive line bundle $L$ (here I regard $\bar{M}_{g,n}$ 
as a complex space rather than a stack). For every finite-index subgroup $Mod^o_{g,n}\subset Mod_{g,n}$, the quotient $M^o_{g,n}=T_{g,n}/Mod^o_{g,n}$ admits a compactification to a complex space $\bar{M}^o_{g,n}$ and a holomorphic branched cover $f: \bar{M}^o_{g,n}\to \bar{M}_{g,n}$. ...

Comment: Pull-back bundle $f^*(L)$ on $\bar{M}^o_{g,n}$ is still positive, so 
$\bar{M}^o_{g,n}$ is projective (by Kodaira) provided that it is a complex manifold. The latter you get by taking $Mod^o_{g,n}$ to be any finite-index subgroup in an appropriate congruence-subgroup in $Mod_{g,n}$ (as in Looijenga's paper on Prym level structures http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~looij101/prymlevel2.ps). 

Projectivity of the rest of quotients of $T_{g,n}$ by finite-index subgroups in $Mod_{g,n}$ follows by taking finite quotients of $M^o_{g,n}$'s above. 

Comment: @Misha, so what you told me in the comments look good, I like this idea of using an explicit positive line bundle. So concerning your addendum keep in mind that not all finite index subgroups are congruence subgroups. So I don't quite understand why your $X_d(N)$ is projective... 

Comment: @Hugo: Of course, there will be non-congruence finite covers, for them you argue as follows. Every non-congruence finite cover $C_1$ and a congruence-cover $C_2$ (of the original complex space/variety) have a common finite regular cover $C_3\to C_1$, $C_3\to C_2$. Since you know that $C_2$ is quasi-projective, it follows that $C_3$ is also quasi-projective (pull-back of positive bundle is positive). But finite quotient $C_1$ of the quasi-projective variety $C_3$ is then quasi-projective as well. 

Comment: Yes of course you are right!

Answer (score 3):

The point is that by your construction $f:\mathcal{E}_\Gamma\to Y_\Gamma$ is an elliptic surface with a *section* $\sigma$. So as Keerthi said in the comments, $f$ is projective. In fact the relative divisor $3\sigma$ gives the Weirstrass embedding $\mathcal{E}_\Gamma\to \mathbb{P}(f_*\mathcal{O}(3\sigma))$).
(Ben's comment shows that projectivity can fail without a section.) 
From here, quasiprojectivity is
straight forward: If $V$ is an extension of 
$f_*\mathcal{O}(3\sigma)$ to a vector bundle on  the smooth projective closure  of $ Y_\Gamma$, then the closure of $\mathcal{E}_\Gamma$ in $\mathbb{P}(V)$ is a projective variety.
Therefore $\mathcal{E}_\Gamma$ is quasiprojective.

---

Given the endless stream of comments, perhaps I should add a few words of clarification:

1. Since $Y=Y_\Gamma$ is noncompact, any vector bundle such as $f_*\mathcal{O}(3\sigma)$ is in fact (analytically)
   trivial. This is definitely overkill, but you can use Grauert, "Analytichse Faserungen..." Math. Ann 1958.
2. Thus $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}(3\sigma))\cong Y\times \mathbb{P}^2$. This
   embeds into  $\bar{Y}\times \mathbb{P}^2$, where $\bar Y$ is a (the) smooth projective compactification of $Y$.
3. We can take the closure of $\mathcal{E}_\Gamma$ to get a projective variety, and the quasiprojectivity of this family follows easily.
4. Note that the fibres of the closure $\overline{\mathcal{E}_\Gamma}$ may be singular.
5. If the Hopf surface had a section, it would lift to a rational curve in $\mathbb{C}^2-\lbrace 0\rbrace$. Well, I'll let you think about why that might be a problem.

---

OK, I guess there some issues.... I'm converting this to CW. Anyone, who wants to fix this
is welcome to. I've got to finishing my refereeing....

Comment: Donu, I think I'm missing something important here. Say that you take the universal elliptic curve $E\rightarrow \mathbf{C}-\{0,1728\}$, then you cannot extend your vector bundle over the smooth projective closure of $\mathbf{C}-\{0,1728\}$ which is $\mathbf{C}$, since there is no universal elliptic curve over $\mathbf{C}$. So may be you could develop a little bit what you mean when you say extending the vector bundle to the smooth projective locus.

Comment: the 3rd $\mathbf{C}$ should be replaced by $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbf{C})$ of course.

Comment: Hugo, these are separate issues. A vector bundle on a punctured disk
is trivial, so it extends. So applying this remark and the above construction, we see $E$ extends to a family of possibly *singular* cubics over $0$ and $1728$.

Comment: Well holomorphic vector bundles over (connected) non-compact Riemann surfaces are trivial in the analytic category since the construction 
of sections which trivialize your bundle is transcendental but I don't see why it should trivialize in the algebraic category.

Comment: @Donu, I'm a bit puzzle by what you said about the existence of a section. Take $Y=(\mathbf{C}^2-(0,0))/<(2,2)>$, then it seems to me that the map $s:\mathbf{P}^1\rightarrow Y$ given by $s(x)=(2,2)$ gives you section of your elliptic fibration. In this case, all fibers are isomorphic to the elliptic curve $\mathbf{C}^{\times}/<2>$.

Comment: It suffices to extend in the analytic category, and then invoke GAGA
to conclude the extended bundle is algebraic. 

Comment: Well I don't think you can always extend it in the analytic category when the base has a non-trivial fundamental group.

Comment: @ Donu: Don't you need projective to apply GAGA? Then how can you be sure the bundle you are starting with is algebraic?

Comment: Shouldn't you need the vector bundle to be algebraically trivial? And that is certainly not true. For a curve minus a single point, the line bundle group is the Jacobian, nontrivial unless the curve is rational.

Comment: I'm confused. Do semi-continuity and base change not apply for proper maps of analytic spaces? This is all you need to conclude that $f_*\mathcal{O}(3\sigma)$ is trivial.

Comment: Also, what is the universal elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}-\{0,1728\}$? 

Comment: @Keerthi: For the first question, I'm not sure. For the second, take the Weirstrauss form $y^2=x^3-tx-t$ and compute $j$. The map $t\to j$ is rational linear, thus has an inverse. The bad points $t=0,t=\infty, \Delta=0$ correspond to $j=0$, $j=1728$, and $j=\infty$, thus you can consider it a family over $|mathbb C-\{0,1728\}$.

Comment: Probably $y^2=x^3-tx-t$ is not universal in some functorial sense (because it does not parametrise families with $j$-invariant not 0 or 1728 over arbitrary bases), it's universal in the much weaker sense that it happens to go through each $j$-invariant not 0 or 1728 exactly once. I think calling it "the universal elliptic curve" might cause confusion not least because of the implicit implication of uniqueness.

Comment: @Donu, note that my non-trivial section $s:P^1(\mathbf{C})\rightarrow Y$ for the Hopf surface $Y=(C^2-(0,0))/<(2,2)>$ is given by $s([x_0,x_1])\mapsto [2x_0,2x_1]$. 

Comment: @Kevin, I agree that the terminology "universal elliptic curve" (away from $0$ and $1728$) confusing but I could not come up with a better terminology.

Comment: Ok I was being stupid, ma section is not well defined.